# External GPU with Mac OSX?

Tags: graphics-cards

I'm looking for an external GPU to use with a Macbook Pro, with Thunderbolt 2 and running OSX. Most of the examples I've found online are of people using an eGPU for gaming, dual-booting on Windows 10, on Mac hardware. That's not my goal.

Products like what's on [this Kickstarter campaign](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/thewolfe/the-wolfe-supercharge-your-laptop?ref=nav_search), or [BizonBox](https://bizon-tech.com/us/bizonbox2-egpu.html/), are supposedly designed to work with Mac hardware *and software*. However, Bizonbox for example lists the Nvidia GTX 1060 and up as Windows only. I assume that's because of the availability of Thunderbolt hardware.

What I want is a GPU that will work with Mac OSX, and an enclosure that supports both Thunderbolt 2 and 3 – or if not both, then can be upgraded when I upgrade my laptop. Is this possible?

Comment: Why is it off-topic as technical support request? At least, requirements are too-broad (price, intended usage etc.) but here the OP is clearly asking for a eGPU via Thunderbolt for its MacOS X Macbook pro. @Aidan Miles: Have you looked the BizonBox's solution?

Comment: Yeah, definitely not trying to ask for technical support, though I can understand if this is too broad. The BizonBox suggestion is a good one, and should help me clarify my question.

Comment: Well in the current phrasing of your question, you do ask for technical-support here: "Can I safely assume that the ones listed as Mac-friendly will work with Mac OSX?" just rephrase your question saying something like that : "I want a eGPU for my Macbook [precise your macbook here] [precise the intended usage here]. As an exemple of what I want, I found these products [kickstarter / bizonbox] but they seems to be limited to windows". Still the same question behind, but different phrasing that will please moderators.